# Create a function to convert 'M/D/YYYY' date to 'YYYYMMDD' date in JS

Tags: javascript

This is a practice interview question related to JS I found online. I have tried to complete it and added code below. My question is would my code be a acceptable answer to the question: Create a function to convert a 'M/D/YYYY' formatted date to a 'YYYYMMDD' formatted date in JS?

```
function formattedUserDate(userInput) {
    const formatDate = userInput
    const apiDateForm = formatDate.split('/')
    let formatDateMonth = apiDateForm[0]
    let formatDateDay = apiDateForm[1]
    let formatDateYear = apiDateForm[2]
    
    formatDateMonth.length == 1 ? formatDateMonth = '0' + formatDateMonth : null;
    formatDateDay.length == 1 ? formatDateDay = '0' + formatDateDay : null;

    const apiDateFormArray = [formatDateYear, formatDateMonth, formatDateDay];
    return apiDateFormArray.join('');
}

console.log(formattedUserDate('5/1/1987'));
```

Comment: I doubt any reviewer would want to see a console.log() returned. That is always undefined

Comment: The console.log was for me to see it working in the dev tools! But thanks.

Comment: In which case, do instead: `return apiDateFormArray.join('');` then `console.log(formattedUserDate('5/1/1987'));` ?

Comment: Well it is in the code you asked about. If that's not what you would provide the interviewer then it shouldn't be there

Comment: This question is more appropriate to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Check the help section there on how to ask and what is and what isn't on topic first though

Comment: The incorrect use of the ternaries in the code would drop you off. Ternary operator is not a shortcut to `if .. else` syntax, and even worse, you're not using the `else` part at all.

Comment: @charlietfl I suppose this is not a suitable question for codereview. They provide the code being real production code, not an arbitrary piece of code for an interview.

Comment: should be pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
function formattedUserDate(userInput) {
  const apiDateForm = userInput.split('/')
  let formatDateMonth = `0${apiDateForm[0]}`.slice(-2);
  let formatDateDay = `0${apiDateForm[1]}`.slice(-2);
  let formatDateYear = apiDateForm[2]
  const apiDateFormArray = [formatDateYear, formatDateMonth, formatDateDay];
  return console.log(apiDateFormArray.join(''));
}

formattedUserDate('5/1/1987')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript have new method **padStart** and **padEnd** has below syntax.

"your_string".padStart(targetLength [,padString]):

```js
function formattedUserDate(userInput) {
    const formatDate = userInput
    const apiDateForm = formatDate.split('/')
    let formatDateMonth = apiDateForm[0]
    let formatDateDay = apiDateForm[1]
    let formatDateYear = apiDateForm[2]
    
    formatDateMonth = formatDateMonth.padStart(2, "0")
    formatDateDay = formatDateDay.padStart(2, "0")
    
    const apiDateFormArray = [formatDateYear, formatDateMonth, formatDateDay];
    return console.log(apiDateFormArray.join(''));
}

formattedUserDate('5/1/1987');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that may be a correct answer. But your code must be clean and clear like that :)

```js
function formattedUserDate(userInput) {

         const date = userInput.split("/");

         let day   = date[1],
             month = date[0], 
             year  = date[2];
        
         return (year + formatter(month) + formatter(day));
}
        
        
const formatter = text => text < 10 ? ('0' + text) : text;
        

console.log("date formatted : " + formattedUserDate('5/1/1987'))
```

Comment: you're right. thank's :). I'll correct it